# Rails: How to validate an specific state of an object without changing its attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a Model with the column `completed`. To set `completed` to true, it has to match certain validations to become valid.

Is there some easy way to check out if an object is valid with `completed` set to true without actually changing the attribute of an object?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
def ready_for_completion?
  self.completed = true
  ready = self.valid?
  self.completed = false
  ready
end
```

But I think there is a much nicer way to do this, just haven't found out how.

**UPDATE:**

I should have been more accurate.

My problem is view specific, I have a button on a object which sets `completed` to `true` after hitting it and I want that button to be disabled if the object is not ready for completion.

Comment: Could you post the conditions for an object to be considered ready for completion?

Comment: Also, isn't that column redundant with the object validation itself?

Answer (score 3):

I would not `validate` your `completed` field. It is your responsibility to set this attribute when you feel that your "object" is completed.

You should take a look at [state machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

Comment: I should have been more accurate. My problem is view specific, I have a button on a object which sets `completed` to `true` and I want that button to be disabled if the object is not ready for completion. +1 for the state machine gem, didn't know about it.

Comment: ok, you could totally handle the "completion" logic by the state machine. You fire your state machine callback when someone click on that link and check before doing any changes if the object is valid for completion or not. If not, return false to handle the error case.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is correct, however I would wrap it into a method

```
def as_completed
  old_completed = completed
  self.completed = true
  result = yield
  self.completed = old_completed
  result
end
```

Then

```
def ready_for_completion?
  as_completed { valid? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just you can use valid? for test model is valid or not in controller/view/model as
per below example:
      if model.valid?
       #your code
      end
    ===============
    class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :name, presence: true
    end

    Person.create(name: "John Doe").valid? # => true
    Person.create(name: nil).valid? # => false
```